# structured quad mesh with transition zone

Tags: mesh

I wonder which software can be used to generate the mesh like below. Anybody has an idea?

[image]

Comment: You could generate that by hand.

Comment: I would guess so. I could imagine an algorithm that works in 2D. I saw this mesh a lot in the literature but have not seen in any textbook on adaptive FEM.

Comment: @ksth Adaptive finite element software is widely available today. You might want to take a look at some of the big finite element libraries. Separately, I would recommend the textbook by Graham Carey about computational meshes.